# Getting CERT_UNTRUSTED while executeing command on terminal

Tags: node.js, ssl-certificate, npm

I have **node (v0.10.22)** and **npm (1.3.14)** installed on my system.

I am trying to execute below command.

```
echo "require('https').request({host: 'host.net'}, function(res){console.log(res.statusCode)}).end()" | NPM_DEBUG=https node
```

and getting error on terminal as below

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: CERT_UNTRUSTED
    at SecurePair.<anonymous> (tls.js:1362:32)
    at SecurePair.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
    at SecurePair.maybeInitFinished (tls.js:974:10)
    at CleartextStream.read [as _read] (tls.js:462:15)
    at CleartextStream.Readable.read (_stream_readable.js:320:10)
    at EncryptedStream.write [as _write] (tls.js:366:25)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:221:10)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:211:5)
    at EncryptedStream.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:180:11)
    at write (_stream_readable.js:583:24)
```

The above command is working fine with **node (v0.6.12)** but not for **node (v0.10.22)**

I also tried below things but still its not working

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm config set ca ""
```

Can anyone please help on this ?